# Convert net.sf.ehcache.CacheManger to org.springframework.cache.CacheManager?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache

I have an application that runs locally with a bean in `Application.java` for Spring Boot called cacheManager

```
@Bean(name="cacheManager")
 @Primary
 public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
     return new EhCacheCacheManager();
}
```

Since it worked locally I deployed to a server and apparently there is another application with a CacheManger that's competing for it's space
because I get following stacktrace:

> Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager
>   already exists in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each
>   CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
>   1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
>   2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name. The source of the existing CacheManager is:
>   DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.assertNoCacheManagerExistsWithSameName(CacheManager.java:626)
>     at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:391)  at
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.(CacheManager.java:269)     at
>   org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerUtils.buildCacheManager(EhCacheManagerUtils.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheCacheManager.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>     ... 32 common frames omitted

I attempted to put

```
@Bean(name="cacheManager")
@Primary
public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
    return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create();
}
```

but then `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManger.create()` doesn't return a spring CacheManger. I tried changing the returning CacheManager to net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager, but I get this locally:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CacheResolver
>   specified, and no unique bean of type CacheManager found. Mark one as
>   primary (or give it the name 'cacheManager') or declare a specific
>   CacheManager to use, that serves as the default one.  at
>   org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.afterSingletonsInstantiated(CacheAspectSupport.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:781)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 42 more

I think converting is the answer, but the answer could also be some sly code move.
Suggestions?
Extra Information: This is in a webservice

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38570211/how-to-have-multiple-cache-manager-configuration-in-spring-cache-java

Comment: Ehcaches within the same JVM must have unambiguous `CacheManager` names. `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factory = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean(); factory.setCacheManagerName("MyUniqueCache"); EhCacheCacheManager manager = new EhCacheCacheManager(); manager.setCacheManager(manager);` will get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem was to let Spring decide the cache manager, so all I needed to do was add @EnableCaching on my Application.java and then use @Cacheable on the methods I wanted to cache on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you deploy an `ehcache.xml` configuration file for Ehcache, you get the default embedded configuration. This configuration does not name the `CacheManager` and as the first exception indicates, you cannot have more than one in a single JVM.

The easiest solution is to have an `ehcache.xml`, not in a package, and then it will be picked up by your deployment.